# lpSolve in R with Character and Column Sum Contraints

Tags: r, optimization, constraints, linear-programming, lpsolve

I have a list of rooms, the rooms' maximum square feet, programs, the programs' maximum square feet, and the values of how well a room matches (match #) the intended program use. With help, I have been able to maximize match # and square feet use for one program per room. However, I would like to take this analysis one step further and allow for multiple programs in the same room or multiples of the same program if it has the highest match #, so long as the multiples still fit within the square foot requirements. Moreover, I would like to tell lpSolve overall that I only want "x" number of Offices, "y" number of Studios, etc. throughout the entire building. Here is my data and code thus far:

```
program.size <- c(120,320,300,800,500,1000,500,1000,1500,400,1500,2000)
room.size <- c(1414,682,1484,2938,1985,1493,427,1958,708,581,1485,652,727,2556,1634,187,2174,205,1070,2165,1680,1449,1441,2289,986,298,590,2925)
(obj.vals <- matrix(c(3,4,2,8,3,7,4,8,6,4,7,7,
                  3,4,2,8,3,7,4,8,6,4,7,7,
                  4,5,3,7,4,6,5,7,5,3,6,6,
                  2,3,1,7,2,6,3,7,7,5,6,6,
                  4,5,3,7,4,6,5,7,5,3,6,6,
                  3,6,4,8,5,7,4,8,7,7,7,7,
                  3,4,2,8,3,7,4,8,6,4,7,7,
                  4,5,3,7,4,6,5,7,5,3,6,6,
                  6,7,5,7,6,6,7,7,5,3,6,6,
                  6,7,5,7,6,6,7,7,5,3,6,6,
                  5,6,6,6,5,7,8,6,4,2,5,5,
                  6,7,5,7,6,6,7,7,5,3,6,6,
                  6,7,5,7,6,6,7,7,5,3,6,6,
                  3,4,4,8,3,9,6,8,6,4,7,7,
                  3,4,2,6,3,5,4,6,6,4,5,5,
                  4,5,3,5,4,4,5,5,5,3,4,4,
                  5,6,4,8,5,7,6,8,6,4,7,7,
                  5,6,4,8,5,7,6,8,6,4,7,7,
                  4,5,5,7,4,8,7,7,5,3,6,6,
                  5,6,4,8,5,7,6,8,6,4,7,7,
                  3,4,2,6,3,5,4,6,6,4,5,5,
                  5,6,4,8,5,7,6,8,6,4,7,7,
                  5,6,4,8,5,7,6,8,6,4,7,7,
                  5,4,4,6,5,5,6,6,6,6,7,5,
                  6,5,5,5,6,4,5,5,5,7,6,4,
                  4,5,3,7,4,6,5,7,7,5,6,6,
                  6,5,5,5,6,4,5,5,5,7,6,4,
                  3,4,4,6,3,7,6,6,6,4,5,5), nrow=12))
rownames(obj.vals) <- c("Enclosed Offices", "Open Office", "Reception / Greeter", "Studio / Classroom",
                    "Conference / Meeting Room", "Gallery", "Public / Lobby / Waiting", 
                    "Collaborative Space", "Mechanical / Support", "Storage / Archives", 
                    "Fabrication", "Performance")
(obj.adj <- obj.vals * outer(program.size, room.size, "<="))


nr <- nrow(obj.adj)
nc <- ncol(obj.adj)

library(lpSolve)
obj <- as.vector(obj.adj)
con <- t(1*sapply(1:nc, function(x) rep(1:nc == x, each=nr)))
dir <- rep("<=", nc)
rhs <- rep(1, nc)
mod <- lp("max", obj, con, dir, rhs, all.bin=TRUE)

final <- matrix(mod$solution, nrow=nr)
```

And so now my question is how can I allow the solver to maximize square foot use and match # within each room (column) and allow either multiple of the same programs or a combination of programs to accomplish this? I know I would have to lift the "<= 1" restriction in "mod", but I can't figure out how to let it find the best fit in each room and then ultimately, overall.

The solution that should come for room [,1] is:

```
$optimum
33
```

And it's going to try to fit 11 Enclosed Offices within the room which scores a much higher optimum match # than 1 Collaborative Space (8 matches) and 1 Storage / Archives (4 matches) for a total of 12 matches.

And so this leads to my next question about limiting the overall number of certain programs within my solution matrix. I assume it would include some kind of

```
as.numeric(data$EnclosedOffices "<=" 5)
```

but I also can't figure out how to limit that. These numbers would be different for all the programs.

Thanks for any and all help and feel free to ask for any clarification.

---

**Update:**
Constraints

- Maximize the match # (obj.vals) for each room.
- Maximize the    program.size square feet within each room.size square
  feet. Do this    by either using the same program multiple times (5 x
  Enclosed    Offices) or combining programs (1 Collaborative Space and
  1    Performance).
- Restrict and/or force the number of programs returned in the
  solution. The programs can be split up among rooms so long as it doesn't go over the maximum number I provide for that program in all the rooms. (Only 5 Enclosed Offices, 8 Studios/Classrooms, 1 Fabrication, etc. can be selected across all 28 columns.

Comment: Can you explain the objective and constraints a bit more? You have 28 rooms and 12 different *types* of "programs." Is the goal to fit as many of programs as possible? Can a program be split across rooms? Describing your constraints before you present the code would help. Thanks.

Comment: @RamNarasimhan - I updated at the bottom of my OP with more specific constraints.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use the R package `lpSolveAPI` (a wrapper for lpSolve) then it becomes a little easier.
First, take a look at the mathematical formulation (an Integer Program) and then I show you the code to solve your problem.

### Formulation

Let `X_r_p` be the decision variable that takes on positive integer values.

`X_r_p` = Number of programs of type `p` assigned to room `r`
(In all your problem will have 28*12=336 decision variables)

**Objective Function**

Maximize matching score

`Max sum(r) sum(p) C_r_p * X_r_p` # Here C_r_p is the score of assigning p to room r

*Subject to*

**Room Area Limitation Constraint**

```
Sum(p) Max_area_p * X_r_p <= Room Size (r) for each room r
```

(We will have 28 such constraints)

**Restrict the Number of programs Constraint**

```
Sum(r) X_r_p <= Max_allowable(p) for each program p
```

(We will have 12 such constraints)

```
 X_r_p >= 0, Integer
```

That is the formulation in all. 336 columns and 40 rows.

**Implementatin in R**

Here's an implementation in R, using `lpSolveAPI`.
Note: Since the OP didn't provide the max_allowable programs in the building, I generated my own data for `max_programs.`

```
program.size <- c(120,320,300,800,500,1000,500,1000,1500,400,1500,2000)
    room.size <- c(1414,682,1484,2938,1985,1493,427,1958,708,581,1485,652,727,2556,1634,187,2174,205,1070,2165,1680,1449,1441,2289,986,298,590,2925)
    (obj.vals <- matrix(c(3,4,2,8,3,7,4,8,6,4,7,7,3,4,2,8,3,7,4,8,6,4,7,7,
4,5,3,7,4,6,5,7,5,3,6,6,2,3,1,7,2,6,3,7,7,5,6,6, 4,5,3,7,4,6,5,7,5,3,6,6,
3,6,4,8,5,7,4,8,7,7,7,7,3,4,2,8,3,7,4,8,6,4,7,7, 4,5,3,7,4,6,5,7,5,3,6,6,
6,7,5,7,6,6,7,7,5,3,6,6,6,7,5,7,6,6,7,7,5,3,6,6, 5,6,6,6,5,7,8,6,4,2,5,5,
6,7,5,7,6,6,7,7,5,3,6,6, 6,7,5,7,6,6,7,7,5,3,6,6, 3,4,4,8,3,9,6,8,6,4,7,7,
3,4,2,6,3,5,4,6,6,4,5,5, 4,5,3,5,4,4,5,5,5,3,4,4, 5,6,4,8,5,7,6,8,6,4,7,7,
5,6,4,8,5,7,6,8,6,4,7,7, 4,5,5,7,4,8,7,7,5,3,6,6, 5,6,4,8,5,7,6,8,6,4,7,7,
3,4,2,6,3,5,4,6,6,4,5,5, 5,6,4,8,5,7,6,8,6,4,7,7, 5,6,4,8,5,7,6,8,6,4,7,7,
5,4,4,6,5,5,6,6,6,6,7,5, 6,5,5,5,6,4,5,5,5,7,6,4, 4,5,3,7,4,6,5,7,7,5,6,6,
6,5,5,5,6,4,5,5,5,7,6,4, 3,4,4,6,3,7,6,6,6,4,5,5), nrow=12))
rownames(obj.vals) <- c("Enclosed Offices", "Open Office", "Reception / Greeter", "Studio / Classroom",
                        "Conference / Meeting Room", "Gallery", "Public / Lobby / Waiting", 
                        "Collaborative Space", "Mechanical / Support", "Storage / Archives", 
                        "Fabrication", "Performance")
```

For each of the 12 programs, let's set a maximum number of repetitions that can be assigned to all rooms combined. Note this is something that I added, since this data was not provided by the OP. (Restrict them from getting assigned to too many rooms.)

```
max_programs <- c(1,2,3,1,5,2,3,4,1,3,1,2)
    
library(lpSolveAPI)

nrooms <- 28
nprgs <- 12
ncol = nrooms*nprgs

lp_matching <- make.lp(ncol=ncol)
#we want integer assignments
set.type(lp_matching, columns=1:ncol, type = c("integer"))

# sum r,p Crp * Xrp
set.objfn(lp_matching, obj.vals) #28 rooms * 12 programs
lp.control(lp_matching,sense='max')

#' Set Max Programs constraints
#' No more than max number of programs over all the rooms
#' X1p + x2p + x3p ... + x28p <= max(p) for each p
Add_Max_program_constraint <- function (prog_index) {
  prog_cols <- (0:(nrooms-1))*nprgs + prog_index
  add.constraint(lp_matching, rep(1,nrooms), indices=prog_cols, rhs=max_programs[prog_index])
}
#Add a max_number constraint for each program
lapply(1:nprgs, Add_Max_program_constraint)

#' Sum of all the programs assigned to each room, over all programs 
#' area_1 * Xr1+ area 2* Xr2+ ... + area12* Xr12 <= room.size[r] for each room
Add_room_size_constraint <- function (room_index) {
  room_cols <- (room_index-1)*nprgs + (1:nprgs) #relevant columns for a given room
  add.constraint(lp_matching, xt=program.size, indices=room_cols, rhs=room.size[room_index])
}
#Add a max_number constraint for each program
lapply(1:nrooms, Add_room_size_constraint)
```

To solve this:

```
> solve(lp_matching)
> get.objective(lp_matching)
 [1] 195
get.variables(lp_matching) # to see which programs went to which rooms

> print(lp_matching)
Model name: 
  a linear program with 336 decision variables and 40 constraints
```

You can also write the IP model to a file to examine it:

```
#Give identifiable column and row names
rp<- t(outer(1:nrooms, 1:nprgs, paste, sep="_"))
rp_vec <- paste(abc, sep="")
colnames<- paste("x_",rp_vec, sep="")
# RowNames
rownames1 <- paste("MaxProg", 1:nprgs, sep="_")
rownames2 <- paste("Room", 1:nrooms, "AreaLimit", sep="_")
dimnames(lp_matching) <- list(c(rownames1, rownames2), colnames)

write.lp(lp_matching,filename="room_matching.lp")
```

Hope that helps.

## Update based on follow-up questions

Follow up Question 1: *Alter the code to ensure that every room has at least one program.*

Add the following constraint set:

```
X_r_p >= 1 for all r
```

Note: Since this is a maximization problem, the optimal solution should honor this constraint by default. In other words, it will always assign a program to any room if it could, assuming positive scores for assigning.

Follow up question 2: *Another question is if I can ask it to have more than 28 programs in total? For instance, if I want 28 Enclosed Offices they almost all could fit in the one room with 2938 square feet. How then can I ask R to still find other programs if the max is set for 28?*

In order to achieve this goal, you can do it a bit differently. Do not have the sum of all programs <= 28 constraint at all. (If you note in the solution above, my constraints are slightly different.)

The constraint:

```
 Sum(r) X_r_p <= Max_allowable(p) for each program p
```

only limits the max per *type* of program. There is no limit on the total. Also, you don't have to write one such constraint for each type of program. Write this constraints only if you want to limit its occurrence.

To generalize this, you can set the lower and upper bounds for the total of each type of programs. This will give you very fine control over the assignments.

```
min_allowable(p) <= sum(over r) X_r_p <= max_allowable(p) for any program type p
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much for your help with this.

Comment: I do have follow up questions. 
(1) How can I alter the code so that I can have the sum of max_programs <- c(1,2,3,1,5,2,3,4,1,3,1,2) be less than 28, but have the code be sure that every room has at least one program? Another question is if I can ask it to have more than 28 programs in total? For instance, if I want 28 Enclosed Offices they almost all could fit in the one room with 2938 square feet. How then can I ask R to still find other programs if the max is set for 28?

(2) Is there an easy way to see the results? I can't open a .lp file.

Comment: I will respond to your extra questions as soon as I find the time. The *.lp file is just a text file. You can open it with any text editor.

Comment: Hey @RamNarasimhan, I apologize if I'm being pushy, but have you had a chance to look at my follow up questions?

Comment: Thank you for the update. The solution works very nicely. Only using the upper limits has been working for me so far. However, when I apply a sum of 31 max_programs across the rows, lpsolveAPI runs very slowly and takes minutes at a time. Is this common? Or is this how my solution is set up? Or is it just my computer? Thanks again!

Comment: No, it is not your computer. That particular constraint is structurally 'bad' for the integer program. If you can live with the delay, then that's fine. There are some techniques to make it a little faster (constraint relaxations), but basically that constraint makes it difficult for the branch-and-bound algorithm.

Comment: Thanks again. I tried running it this morning with 28 max_programs but with 6 Enclosed Offices and it also appears that large max_program numbers for individual programs causes it to run slowly, I cancelled it after 2 hours. Do you have any good suggestions for constraint relaxation or alternative solving methods or packages?

Comment: For constraint relaxation, you have to read up on Linear and Integer programming. One quick suggestion: drop the Integer constraint. Then it becomes a linear program and should run in seconds. Note that *fractional* programs will get assigned to rooms. This will give you an Upper limit on the objective value

Comment: Dropping the integer constraint did make it work instantaneously! It also told me to put ~300 Enclosed Offices into my building, ha! This is where my hands are kind of tied and I need to limit the total number possible of the rooms with the smallest square feet.